Does Halo Infinite have an in-game FPS Counter?
I'd like to see how much FPS I'm getting in Halo Infinite, but I don't want to use a third-party FPS Counter.
Does Halo Infinite have a built-in in-game FPS Counter?
If yes, then where and how can I activate it?

According to this video, if you go to the settings menu, and click on the gameplay tab, then scroll down, you will see a check box that says FPS COUNTER in all caps. Check that, and it'll show the fps in the top right. If you check NETWORK STATISTICS as well, you can see ping and latency data.
Note that this is apparently only for Xbox and PC.

Okay, here is how you can activate Halo Infinite built-in FPS counter:

Open Halo Infinite
Go to the Settings menu.
Select the UI tab.
Scroll down to find the FPS Counter option.
Toggle this option to On.

